# Matching Pandas DataFrame Column Values with another DataFrame Column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

```
country = []
for i in df_temp['Customer Name'].iloc[:]:
    if i in gui_broker['EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME'].tolist():
        country.append(gui_broker["Book"].values[gui_broker['EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME'].tolist().index(i)])
    else:
        country.append("No Book Defined")
df_temp["Country"] = country
```

I have currently a large DataFrame (df_temp) with one column ('Customer Name') and am trying to match it with a small DataFrame (gui_broker) which has 3 columns - one of which has all unique values of the large DataFrame ('EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME').

After matching the value row of df_temp I want to create a new column in df_temp with the value 'Book' of my small DataFrame (gui_broker) based on the matching. I tried every apply lambda method, but am out of clue. The above provided code provides me with a solution, but it's slow and not Pandas like...

How exactly could I proceed?

Comment: Could you provide [mcve]? It's much easier to help you that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `join` (docs are [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html))
It joins DataFrame with the other by matching the selected column(s) in the first with the index in the second.

So

```
df_temp.join(gui_broker
             .set_index("EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME")
             .loc[:, ["Book"]],
             on="Customer Name")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use pandas merge to do that. like this...

```
df_temp = df_temp.merge(gui_broker[['EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME','Book']], left_on='Customer Name', right_on='EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME', how='left' )
df_temp['Book'] = df_temp['Book'].fillna('No Book Defined')
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it, using [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the `Book` column of `gui_broker` by the `EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME`, onto `Custome Name` in `df_tmp`, :

```
df_tmp['Country'] = (df_tmp['Customer Name']
                     .map(gui_broker.set_index('EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME').Book)
                     .fillna('No Book Defined'))
```

Though I would need some example data to test it with!

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to do that but I get InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. df_tmp['Customer Name'] has many non unique rows. gui_broker('EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME') however just one.

Comment: If you're getting that error, I think it would be that `gui_broker` actually *does* have non-unique rows, in which case you could drop the duplicates of that one first. It should not matter that `df_tmp` has duplicates, only duplicates in the mapping series matter. If that's the case, use `gui_broker.drop_duplicates(subset='EXACT_DDI_CUSTOMER_NAME',inplace=True)` before.

Comment: Trying it with a dummy dataframe, I get that error message when there is a duplicate in `gui_broker`, but not otherwise